# No Value Given For one or more parameters Vb.net Update Statement

Tags: vb.net

This Is My Update Statement and when i try to update access database using it The error "No Given Value for One Or More Parameter ... etc"

Note: "There is some failed i want to keep with no change/update"

```
 sqlupdate = "UPDATE MainData SET [Done]=@Done, [Delevered]=@Delevered, [Called]=@Called, [QussaiCheked]=@QussaiCheked,[Employee]=@Employee,[CustName]=@CustName, [CustPhone]=@CustPhone ," & _
       "[NoSignal]=@NoSignal ,[NoPower]=@NoPower ,[FormatC]=@FormatC ,[FormatAll]=@FormatAll ,[WindXP]=@WindXP ,[Wind7]=@Wind7 ,[Wind8]=@Wind8 ,[DeviseType]=@DeviseType ," & _
       "[Note]=@Note ,[Reciver]=@Reciver,[DateTime]=[DateTime],[Coast]=@Coast WHERE ID='" & Convert.ToInt32(IDLable.Text) & "'"


If (DoneCheckBox.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Done", DoneCheckBox.Checked)
    End If

    If (DeleveredCheck.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delevered", DeleveredCheck.Checked)
    End If
    If (CalledCheck.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Called", CalledCheck.Checked)
    End If
    If (QussaiChecked.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QussaiCheked", QussaiChecked.Checked)
    End If
    If (Employee.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", Employee.Checked)
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", NameTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustPhone", PhoneTextBox.Text)
    If (RadioSignal.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@NoSignal", RadioSignal.Checked))
    End If
    If (RadioPower.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@NoPower", RadioPower.Checked))
    End If
    If (Fc.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormatC", Fc.Checked)
    End If
    If (Fall.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormatAll", Fall.Checked)
    End If
    If (WinXP.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WindXP", WinXP.Checked)
    End If
    If (Win7.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wind7", Win7.Checked)
    End If
    If (Win8.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wind8", Win8.Checked)
    End If
```

'...etc For All Parameters 
'then

```
con1.Open()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
       ' MessageBox.Show(ex.Source)
    End Try
    con1.Close()
    RefreshDGV()
    MessageBox.Show("{updated")
```

I try to post the exception handler message but "Still New Less than 10 Reputation "

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you add the parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Solved My problem thanks for all how view or attempt to solve it   and help my
:)

I Update each field one by one Using this Code:

```
  Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test.accdb")

Public Cmd As OleDbCommand



  Dim Str As String
        Str = "update MainData set CustName="
        Str += """" & NameTextBox.Text & """"
        Str += " where ID="
        Str += IDLable.Text.Trim()
        con1.Open()
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con1)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
```